# Adding array name to anonymous array in a json string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

How can I change this:

```
[{"name": "Donald"}, {"name": "George"}]
```

To this:

```
{MyArray: [{"name": "Donald"}, {"name": "George"}]}
```

This is for a database server I made using node.js, express and body-parser. The string is produced using the collection('name').find().toArray function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the string to an object and use an object with the named property. Stringify the object to a string.

```js
var json = '[{"name": "Donald"}, {"name": "George"}]',
    object = { myArray: JSON.parse(json) };
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: In case you want to work with the key even before you send  (or parse it), here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rx1s1t6/

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var arr = [{"name": "Donald"}, {"name": "George"}]
var obj = {}
obj.MyArray = arr;
```